# Joining point data to nearest polyline with additional attribute criterion in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, attribute-joins, fields-attributes

I am trying to join point data to polylines in ArcMap 10.3.1, for which I have used the Near tool, and that gives me the distance and FIDs of the nearest polylines, and I can then use the FID to join the two datasets. 
However, I would like to use an additional selection criterion that is recorded in the point data to choose the polyline to link to. That is, the nearest polyline is not necessarily the adequate line to join to, but it might be a polyline that is further away, if it has the matching attribute I am looking for.
I added a screenshot of the problem: the yellow point feature needs to be joined to one of the nearby line features, which have different attributes according to their colors. I could of course select the proper line manually, but I have about 5000 points to join, so that's not really efficient...
The selection attribute is the line material, which is recorded in both the point and the line features.
Can anyone help?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Please [edit] your question to include a sample of your attributes and a screenshot showing how these apply to your situation.

Comment: Generate Near Table is where I would recommend to start.. this will give you a table of ALL the from and to features. You should be able to join from this table to points and lines and remove the undesired combinations. Without knowing *exactly* your attributes and requirements I can't be more specific.

Comment: Like I said, start with Generate Near Table (I'm assuming because you can use Near that you have an advanced license) then attribute join the near table to the points and lines, select the rows where point.material <> line.material and remove this will leave you rows where the point and line material match. From here you need to remove the rows where for each point ID there is a greater distance - this is the tricky part, do you have any python ability? If not you can use summary statistics to find the minimum for each case point id, join the stat table by point ID and remove greater dist.

Comment: This should be done with linear referencing rather than the near analysis.  Create routes from your lines using the field you want to join on (ID or whatever it is).  Then locate features along routes using a search radius that will find all the points (furthest distance of point from lines).  The locate features tool will generate a distance field telling you the distance to the line.  Then if you want to, you can snap the points back to the lines by creating an event layer from the locate features output table.